# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии третьего чекбокса переходило по сформированной ссылке?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как по приложенному коду сделать переход по сгенерированной ссылке при активации третьего чекбокса-кнопки, из условия что первый и второй тоже содержат свой кусок url, а третья является финальной?

То есть, получается: первый чекбокс (site.ru/) + второй чекбокс(category/) + третий чекбокс(item.html) = site.ru/category/item.html
И вот когда уже нажат третий чекбокс, должно переходить по полной ссылке site.ru/category/item.html

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
 $('#result').html('');
 $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
  $('#result').append($(this).val());
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 font-size:14px;
 padding: 15px 20px;
}
a {
  baclground: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.no-vis  {
 position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
.no-vis input {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
 <p>
  <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="/sloman-ekarn/">Сломан экран</label><br>
  <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="mi/">Mi</label><br>
 </p>
 <p>
    
    
    
  <button id="btn" class="no-vis btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"><label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="sloman-ekran-mi-8.html"></label>Xiaomi Mi 8</button>
 </p> 
  <p id="result" class="text-success"><a href=""></a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, какая в результате должна быть ссылка, в каком порядке могут быть части - а то сейчас есть /sloman-ekarn/, mi/ и sloman-ekran-mi-8.html.

Comment: @Coder site.ru/sloman-ekarn/mi/sloman-ekran-mi-8.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       $('#btn').click(function(){
            $('#result').html('');
            $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){        
            window.location.href = $(this).val();
             //alert($(this).val());
            });
        });
```

```js
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
  let d = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){ 
return $(this).val();
}).get().join('');
let res = 'https://site.ru/' + d + $('#a3').val();
   //window.location.href = res;
 $('#result a').attr("href", res).text(res);
});
```

```css
body {
 font-size:14px;
 padding: 15px 20px;
}
a {
  /*background: red;*/
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.no-vis  {
 position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
.no-vis input {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
    <label><input class="form-check-input"  type="checkbox" value="sloman-ekarn/">Сломан экран</label><br>
    <label><input class="form-check-input"  type="checkbox" value="mi/">Mi</label><br>
    <input  id="a3" type="hidden" value="sloman-ekran-mi-8.html">
    <button id="btn" class="no-vis btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Xiaomi Mi 8</button>
    <p id="result" class="text-success"><a href="">Результат</a></p>
</div>
Должно быть: site.ru/sloman-ekarn/mi/sloman-ekran-mi-8.html
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему по Вашему коду он вызывает 3 окна alert, как будто ссылка разделяется на три разные? К сожалению, не работает на сайте, необходимо, чтобы плюсовались все три части ссылки (третья заложена в саму button) и должна подсавлять свое значение и одновременно переходить на ссылку из трех частей

Comment: Это в хроме так, в firefox один раз - да это и не важно - алерт здесь не нужен - переход будет спазу по первому совпадению условий. Ага - ну, нужно подумать тогда.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, я знаю, что алерт не нужен, что он для отладки. Сейчас попробую на радио поменять

Comment: Пожалуйста) - немного бы по-подробней в условии про три части ссылки - а то не совсем понятно.

Comment: При радио почему-то не плюсуются куски ссылок в каждом input

Comment: Смотрите, про три части ссылки. В коде каждой задан один кусочек url, который формируется при нажатии на кнопку, в которую вшит третий чекбок. Соответственно, ссылка формируется из трех частей (кусочков url)

Comment: Да - я не предполагал, что есть три части, потому и предложил единственный выбор.

Comment: Извините, это мой косяк, нужно было в вопросе уточнить. Подскажтите, пожалуйста, а как вывести эти все три части в одну ссылку, и чтобы перешло по ней?

Comment: Если вопрос только по конкретному коду, без 100500 чеков)), то не проще проверять два чека на чеккед и при клике на кнопку добавлять последнюю строчку в url?

Comment: @spoon100500 вы правы, у меня планируется 100500 чеков)